# Error during rm ANOVA (Matlab) with random factor

Tags: matlab, error-handling, manova

I am trying to run a repeated measures ANOVA in Matlab with 4 factors including one factor representing my subjects which I want as a random factor.
The code I have is as follows:

```
[p,table,stats] = anovan(COORDS_SUBJ_II,{group_hand,group_stim,group_time,group_subs},'random',4,'varnames',{'HAND','STIM','TIME','SUBS'});
```

Here, all variables have the same dimension, which is 1350x1(all types are 'double').  I checked my code with some proposed code on the net and it matches, yet I keep getting the following error...

```
Error using chi2inv (line 3)
P and V must be of common size or scalars
Error in anovan>varcompest (line 838)
   L = msTerm .* dfTerm ./ chi2inv(1-alpha/2,dfTerm);
Error in anovan>getRandomInfo (line 811)
[varest,varci] = varcompest(ems,randomterms,msTerm,dfTerm,alpha);
Error in anovan (line 296)
                getRandomInfo(msterm,dfterm,mse,dfe,emsMat,randomterm,...
```

My dependent variable (`COORDS_SUBJ_II`) has a couple of NaN's in it, although I ran the code once where I replaced those NaN's with random numbers and it still gives me the same error. I am kind of lost right now and would appreciate any help.

Best

ty

Answer (score 0):

Found it out. A toolbox I downloaded a while ago also had the chi2inv command and this prompted the error =)